# How to initialize a self._nodes array of a sorted free space linked list

Tags: python

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, DataValue, PointerValue):
        self.DataValue = DataValue
        self.PointerValue = PointerValue
    def set_DataValue(self, DataValue):
        self.DataValue = DataValue
    def set_PointerValue(self, PointerValue):
        self.PointerValue = PointerValue
    def get_DataValue(self):
        return self.DataValue
    def get_PointerValue(self):
        return self.PointerValue
    def IsFull(self):
        return self._nextFree == -1
    def __str__(self):
        return self.DataValue + ", next: " + str(self.PointerValue)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._start = -1
        self._nodes = []
        # Next Free slot is at index 1
        self._nextFree = 0
        pass
```

Comment: Why would you keep a "free list"?  Python is better at memory management than you are.  Just release your nodes when you don't need them any more.  Also note that your `IsFull` function belongs in `LinkedList`, not in `ListNode`, although wouldn't that really be "IsEmpty"?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Python implementation of linked list.  All you need for the Node class is a value and a next (or pointer).  What you need in the LinkedList class in a start node and a method to add nodes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = None, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, start = None):
        self.start = start

    def add_item_to_end(self, item):
        my_node = Node(value=item)
        if self.start == None:
            self.start = my_node
        else:
            p = self.start
            while p.next:
                p = p.next
            p.next = my_node

    def toList(self):
        result = []
        if self.start:
            p = self.start
            while p is not None:
                result.append(p.value)
                p = p.next
        return result
```

Here is how you instantiate the LinkedList class and add nodes:

```
my_ll = LinkedList(Node("bread"))
my_ll.add_item_to_end("milk")
print(my_ll.toList()) #['bread', 'milk']
```